# Magento - free shipping based on product weight

Tags: magento

How can I configure free shipping in Magento?

E.g.: if my product is below 30kg, I don't want shipping charges.

I searched a lot, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

what you want are table-rate-shipping fees. The CSV-import-export cycle themes a little bit strange at first. Use a text-editor instead of Excel, because of formatting issues.

[See Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping)

Best Regards
Joachim